# Sage CRM - How to save a date with using the object returned from CRM.FindRecord()

Tags: sage-crm

Given this code:

```
var ToDateDate = new String(Request.Form("Comm_ToDateTime"));
ToDateDate = ToDateDate.split("/");
var newToDateTime = ToDateDate[2]+"-"+ToDateDate[1]+"-"+ToDateDate[0]+" "+Request.Form("Comm_ToDateTime_TIME")+":00.000";
CurrentCommunication("Comm_ToDateTime") = newToDateTime;
CurrentCommunication.SaveChanges();
```

How can i save the date?

This way the date (as Days, month and year) got saved but the hours, minutos does not.

The final output for the `newToDateTime` variable is `2016-19-09 08:50:00.000`

if i use this value (`2016-19-09 08:50:00.000`) in a barehand SQL update, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that i have to build the Date object with the values and then use `getVarDate()` mehtod to to pass from a Date Javascriopt object to a `record’s date field value` which at the end it is the same i was doing :S

Found my answer in this [Sage CRM Community](https://community.sagecrm.com/partner_community/b/hints_tips_and_tricks/archive/2009/04/14/add-subtract-days-to-a-date-and-pass-to-a-record-object.aspx)